# Continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f'(x)>0$ on $(a,b)$ except for a $c$ in $(a,b)$ then $f$ is strictly increasing

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $f'(x)>0$ on $(a, b)$ except at a point
$c \in (a, b)$ where $f'(c)=0$, then $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a, b]$.

I can prove the case without the $c$ using MVT, but not sure how to approach this particular case.

Comment: Break up the interval into $[a, c)$ and $(c, b]$, and prove that $f(x) \lt f(c) \lt f(y)$ whenever $x \in [a, c)$ and $y \in (c, b]$.

Comment: Can someone please explain why the behavior of $f'$ is even possible? I thought derivatives can't have simple discontinuities?

Comment: @fwd For example, $f'(x)=x^2, a=-1, b=1, c=0$.

Comment: @Blumenthal Oh yes I see! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'\geq 0$ we see that $f$ is monotonically increasing. [See my comment below]. Suppose $a<x <y<b$ and $f(x)=f(y)$ Then, by monotonicty, we must have $f(z)=f(x)=f(y)$ for all $z \in (x,y)$ and this implies $f'(z)=0$ for all $z \in (x,y)$ contradicting the hypothesis. Hence, $f$ is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$. Now use continuity to show that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$.

Comment: You can't use the monotonicity of $f$ if that's precisely what you're trying to prove.

Comment: It is given that $f'(x) >0$ if $x \neq c$ and $f'(c)=0$. That makes $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ Hence, $x<y$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$.  @Unai

Answer (score 0):

Let $a \leq x \lt c$.  Then the Mean Value Theorem tells you $f(c)-f(x)=f'(t)(c-x)$ for some $t \in (x, c)$ and since $f'(t) \gt 0$ we therefore know that $f(c) - f(x) \gt 0 \Rightarrow f(c) \gt f(x)$.  Similarly, for any $y \in (c, b], f(c) \lt f(y)$.  You already know how to prove the function is strictly increasing in the intervals $(a, c)$ and $(c, b)$, so you're done.